# Silverlight Scrollviewer, making children fill all of the space

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I've got a scroll viewer within a grid view and the scroll viewer takes up a percentage of the screen.

Within the scroll viewer I have a listbox, which I add items to in code.

The problem is that I can't get the listbox to take up all of the space available within the parent scrollviewer.

Just wondering if this is even possible.

Thanks,

Matt

EDIT:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Margin="0,8,0,0"     Loaded="LayoutRoot_Loaded">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.06*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.06*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.88*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.155*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.845*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  ...
   <ListBox x:Name="lstReportTypes" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="#FF737FE0" FontSize="10.667" Background="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="lstReportTypes_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" Foreground="#FF737FE0" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 2" Foreground="#FF737FE0" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="item 3dafasdfasdfasdfsdfasdfasdfasdf" Foreground="#FF737FE0" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand"/>
   </ListBox>
```

The code above is a small snippet of the code, the listbox appears in the correct position and with the correct width. 
The items do not seem to take all of the parents width though, they all clip. If I select one of the items the selected outline is the correct width however.

Hope this extra information helps

Comment: this is not how the scroll viewer works, so no it is not possible

Comment: Your XAML would be great to have to see what we can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `ScrollViewer` if you intend to have only a `ListBox` inside, taking the whole space. A `ListBox` already displays scroll bars when its content exceeds the available space.

You can separately control which scrollbar appears with `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"`.

If you have more elements in you `ScrollViewer` please give more details.

**EDIT:**
The XAML you provided gave me this result (with a pink backgound to show the listbox boundaries):

[image: Silverlight sample capture]

The whole listbox is scrolled and the items are clipped. Isn't that the desired effect? If you want each listbox item to scroll separately you need to specify a custom `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the data within the listbox is still being clipped.
I've removed the scrollviewer and instead the listbox is the only control in the grid section.
The listbox itself takes up the correct amount of space but the items that are added into the listbox via code don't fill all of the available space and they clip.

Comment: I added a screen capture which looks as expected to me (with a pink backgound to show the listbox boundaries). Can you explain what is what you expected?

Comment: I managed to fix this, there was a custom style attached to the listbox items which was cutting the text off.